# redirect a sub domain on server 1 to a folder on another server. both on shared hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web-hosting

I am not skilled in this field and hence want a solution to this.

I have a domain (www.domain.com) hosted on server 1. I want m.domain.com which is on server 1 to show the contents of the folder(folder name:m.domain.com) which is on server 2. Both are on shared hosting servers.

Answer (score 0):

You haven;t given enough information for a full solution, so I'll need to assume a few items.

First, let's assume server 2 is called `x.domain.com`. On `m.domain.com` you will need to setup your apache config as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName m.example.com

  Redirect / http://x.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

It will redirect all requests from m.example.com to x.example.com.

On `x.example.com` you will need to set the folder `m.domain.com` as your root:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin foo@bar.org
   ServerName x.domain.com
   DocumentRoot /path/to/m.domain.com

   Options -Indexes
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for the reply. I am looking @ a back end function of how this is functioning.i have made a mobile builder but i am unable to get my client's sub domain(m.example.com) pointed out to my server with a different domain. If this is confusing, please check the link. http://mobile-website-helpdesk.com/step-2-see-your-mobile-site-in-action/. Please give me a solution for this